# Linear independent vector sets

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector $\mathbb{K}$-space and be $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4} \in V$. Demonstrate that the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\left \{ v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4} \right \}$ is linear independent
> 2. $\left \{ v_{1} +  v_{4} , v_{2} +  v_{4}, v_{3} +  v_{4}, v_{4} \right \}$ is linear independent

I have done the following to demonstrate equivalence (double implication)

The set  $\left \{ v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4} \right \}$  is linearly independent, so the range of the matrix whose columns are the vectors of that set is equal number of columns. Therefore, the determinant of this matrix, which we will call $A$, cannot be null. In a mathematical way,

$$det(v_{1} | v_{2} | v_{3} | v_{4}) \neq 0$$

Because of the properties of the determinants,

$det( v_{1} +  v_{4} | v_{2} +  v_{4} | v_{3} +  v_{4} | v_{4}) = det(v_{1} | v_{2} | v_{3} | v_{4}) + det(v_{4} | v_{4} | v_{4} | v_{4}) = det(v_{1} | v_{2} | v_{3} | v_{4}) \neq 0$

Then, the set  $\left \{ v_{1} +  v_{4} , v_{2} +  v_{4}, v_{3} +  v_{4}, v_{4} \right \}$ is linear independent.

The other implication would be analogous.

$\blacksquare$

Would the demonstration I put forward be correct?

Answer (score 1):

Almost. However, the computation of $\det(v_1+v_4|v_2+v_4|v_3+v_4|v_4)$ is not correct (although your conclusion is correct: it is not $0$). Since $\det$ is multilinear, you should get $8(=2^3)$ determinants, of which the only one which is not $0$ is, in fat, $\det(v_1|v_2|v_3|v_4)$.

On the other hand, I think that it is more natural to solve this exercise using the definition of linear independence.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: If $a(v_1+v_4)+b(v_2+v_4)+c(v_3+v_4)+d v_4=0$, then $av_1+bv_2+cv_3+(a+b+c+d)v_4=0$. Since $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is linearly independent, $a=b=c=a+b+c+d=0$, and you can deduce from this that $a=b=c=d=0$. The reverse implication is similar.

Comment: I don't understand why you try to express zero as a linear combination of the vectors.

Comment: What's your definition of linear independence?

Comment: A set of vectors is said to be linearly independent if no vector of that set can be expressed as a linear combination of the rest of the vectors belonging to that set.

Comment: Very well. And that's equivalent to the assertion that the only way of expressing zero as a linear combination of elements of your set is when all the coefficients are $0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can’t use determinant in general, as an alternative we have that

$$c_1(v_1+v_4)+c_2(v_2+v_4)+c_3(v_3+v_4)+c_4v_4=0$$

$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4)v_4=0$$

and then obtain $c_i=0$.

Comment: I don't understand why you try to express zero as a linear combination of the vectors.

Comment: We are using the definition since $\sum c_i v_i=0\iff c_i=0$ the given vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Refer to [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearlyDependentVectors.html)

Comment: Why we can say that we obtain $c_{i}=0$?